# Using Python to get Excel data and fill form

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have an excel sheet with data I'd like to input into boxes on a web form.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\jj\\Documents\\python_date_test.xlsx', Sheet_name=0)
(df['bx1'][0])
```

The output of the above code is '2'

When I insert this code into the code I'm using to webcrawl, I get the following error `'TypeError: object of type 'numpy.int64' has no len()'`

Here's the code that produced this error:

```
mea1 = browser.find_element_by_name("data1_14581")
mea1.click()
mea1.send_keys((df['bx1'][0]))
mea1.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
```

mea1 refers to the first box for user input.

How can I get the value of `(df['bx1'][0])` and enter it in to the box?

Comment: It's probably not related to the issue, but you should access the element using `df.loc[0, "bx1"]` instead of `df['bx1'][0]`.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error, it works for me. Pass it to a variable first then try it again

Comment: convert to string, `str(....)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used this package but looking at it I believe you are on the right track, try changing the code to:

```
mea1.send_keys(str((df['bx1'][0])))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @pete-breslin, 1+ for your answer!